# How do I make a page the landing page?

Tags: homepage

On my [website](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mindmap/), I have made a [new page](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/mindmap/homepage/) which I want to set as the homepage. How do I make this page the landing page? Please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Of note, you don't need to create a page and set it as the homepage, if there's a `home.php` in your theme, WordPress will use it, so you can put your homepage template in there. Store settings as options rather than post meta and use the customizer for your UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in to your Admin Panel -> Settings -> Reading ->

and follow this image :

[image]